# Why isn't my Laravel model relationship saving?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Can't figure this one out. I've referred to the docs, but I'm not getting the expected result.
What's happening is that my user model is saving okay, all data persists within my user table, but the avatar table still remains empty. No errors are thrown.

**User model**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Topic');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    public function avatars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Avatar');
    }

}
```

**Avatar Model**

```
class Avatar extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

**And finally, the snippet of code in my controller:**

```
$user = new User;
$user -> email = $newEmail;
$user -> name = $newName;
$user -> username = $newUsername;
$user -> password = Hash::make($newPassword);
$user -> avatars -> gravatar  = $gravatar;
$user -> push();
```

The Avatar tables remains empty following the push.
I'm probably not doing this the correct way I'm sure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$gravatar` is set and you're following Laravel naming conventions, you'll need to `save()` the User model first, then `save()` on the avatars relationship separately, passing in the Avatar model, so you have the `id` of User.

Anything passed to `save()` has to be a model.  assuming `gravatar` is a field in your `avatars` table, you would need to instantiate `Avatar`, set the `gravatar` property, and save the instance of `Avatar` through the `avatars` relationship.

**Try this:**

```
$avatar = new Avatar;
$avatar -> gravatar = 'gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($newEmail);

$user = new User;
$user -> email = $newEmail;
$user -> name = $newName;
$user -> username = $newUsername;
$user -> password = Hash::make($newPassword);

$user -> save();
$user -> avatars() -> save($avatar);
```

Comment: `()` are missing there. You can't save anything on the collection.

Comment: Hmm, gives an error:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given.

For reference, $gravatar is a url string:
$gravatar = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($newEmail);

Comment: ok, i think i get what you're trying to do, however, I'm only guessing what your schema is.  I updated the answer.  If this doesn't work for you, can you post your table fields?

Comment: Sorry, should have given the table schema. But this works brilliantly, thank you!